# Remove cached content on log out

Tags: php, caching

For caching page I set this in index page

```
ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private');
```

Now I want to delete all cached content (want to delete all cached contend from user browser) during a log out process how can I do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following.

```
session_cache_limiter( 'nocache' );
```

OR

```
session_cache_expire(30);
```